# Why Yii Redis cache set() method don't create key specified in first parameter . Which is used for Append command

Tags: php, caching, yii, redis

I am working on PHP 5.3.10 , Yii v1.1.14 and Redis 2.2.12.
I am using CRedisCache for caching (not a extension) .

I tried simple code below

`Yii::app()->cache->set($name, $data, 0);`

This command stores data in redis but key (in redis) of specified value is not equals to first parameter of set() function . (Actually I can use same key to retrieve cache using  `Yii::app()->cache->get($name);`)

Actually I want exact redis key for append value , for appending I am using following code .

```
Yii::app()->cache->executeCommand("APPEND",array("KEY" => $name, "DATA" => $data));
```

Any idea on getting key of redis .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a better aproach is to override generateUniqueKey method and simply return $key instead of hashed key it

like

```
class RedisCache extends CRedisCache
{
    protected function generateUniqueKey($key)
    {
        return $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When we using CRedisCache it extends Ccache.php

```
'class' => 'CRedisCache',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'port' => 6379,
'database' => 0,
'hashKey' => false,
'keyPrefix' => '',
```

set hashkey false so your key will be stored as you  set 
keyPrefix is a string prefixed to every cache key, set that to empty

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem for user defined key using executeCommand()

```
Yii::app()->cache->executeCommand("GET",array("KEY" => $name));

Yii::app()->cache->executeCommand("SET",array("KEY" => $name, "VALUE" => json_encode($data)));
```

Still searching for better approach to solve the problem .

Answer (score 0):

Yii hashes the key(md5) before setting it on the cache server. That's why the key on redis is not equal to the $name parameter of yours.